# Как из одного приложения в контейнере docker выполнить запрос к другому?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть 2 контейнера запущенных на 1 сервере. Известен их ip адрес и они входят в общую docker сеть.

1. Как лучше из 1 контейнера сделать запрос к другому (docker logs) чтобы получить его логи за период?
2. Как лучше выполнить внутри второго контейнера какую нибудь команду находясь в первом? (docker exec)

Comment: т.е. вы хотите отправлять команды в докер демон из контейнера?

Comment: ну да, если это возможно. Собственно интересует как получить логи другого контейнера.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону моунтинга docker.sock и установку docker cli в контейнере, возможно вам подойдет

Answer (score 1):

1. В `/etc/docker/daemon.json` добавить:

```
     {
      "log-driver": "local",
      "log-opts": {
        "max-size": "10m"
      }
     }
```

Перезапустить docker. Эта настройка будет иметь эффект только для новых контейнеров. Для уже существующих - их можно перезаустить с указанием `--log-driver local --log-opt max-size=10m`
После этого логи можно найти в `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/` и уже этот путь можно монтировать в другой контейнер.

2. через ssh